# How to look/peek at previous or next rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

Hi I'm new to power query and I'm stuck on an issue which i hope you can help - I have an audit report looking a records changing status and i want to be able to use the [Time Stamp] of the next record to calculate the datediff.

In Qlikview, i've used peek() and previous() and SQL, lead() and lag() but is there a function i can use in power query(M)

ID    [Old Status] [New Status] [Time Stamp] [Duration]
1        NEW         Estimated     6/1/2015
2        Estimated    Planned      7/1/2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple (maybe slow) solution is to add an index column, and then calculate the difference based on the column of the next/previous column.

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc"),
    Orders_table = Source{[Name="Orders",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Orders_table,{"OrderID", "CustomerID", "OrderDate"}),
    Index = Table.AddIndexColumn(SelectColumns, "Index", 0, 1),
    Diff = Table.AddColumn(Index, "Custom", each [OrderDate] - Index{[Index]-1}[OrderDate])
in
    Diff
```

Comment: That's really nice.  M Code can be obscure, and I got a bit confused with the 2 different "Index" references, but once I pulled it apart in the Editor it made sense. I think for that specific question you might need [Index]+1 to get the "next" record.

Comment: Sorry i thought i posted a reply to this but this helped me out.. i  In the end when for something slightly different using indexes and the List.Skip to look at the previous data in the list  <br> Table.AddColumn(#"Date Index", "Last Date", each try List.Skip(#"Date Index"[Audit Field Change Timestamp],0){[Date Index]}? otherwise 0),